# Finding the density of a random vector of independent gaussians

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, independence

I have a random vector in $R^n$ where each of the elements of the random vector are independently sampled from $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. How would I calculate the distribution of this vector?

Would the proper formula be by independence

$$F_{X_{1}, \ldots, X_{N}}\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{N}\right)=\mathrm{P}\left(X_{1} \leq x_{1}, \ldots, X_{N} \leq x_{N}\right)=\prod_{i=1}^N P(X_i<x_i)$$
And I could plug in the formula for the distribution of each of the gaussians in the product?

Comment: Yes-but addressing your last question: remember you are working with cdfs as you've written the formula above, so there won't be any closed form formula. If you want it in terms of formulas, the same equality is true for pdfs rather than cdfs, where you do have a closed form formula.

Comment: @layabout Why would the CDF not just be $\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{x} e^{-t^{2} / 2} d t$?

Comment: It would be. That isn't a closed form formula (one expressed in an elementary way, e.g., without an integral), though, as there is no such formula for the normal distribution. Because your question asked if you could plug in the formula for the distribution I was not sure if you either wanted the density expressed as a pdf or if you thought there might be a closed form expression for the cdf. You can ignore my comment, then.

Comment: If you changed the inequality at the end to $\prod\limits_{i=1}^N P(X_i\le x_i)$ your statement would be true in general for independent random variables (not just continuous random variables), so you can indeed do what you suggest.

Comment: In your particular example, building on @layabout's comment, the density would be $f_{X_{1}, \ldots, X_{N}}\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{N}\right) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^N f(x_i) = (2 \pi)^{-N/2} e^{-\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^{2} / 2}$